# POST 504 (gateway timeout) error when trying to proxy angular app to node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, express

full error message : POST http://localhost:4200/api/user/login 504 (Gateway Timeout)

when trying to create a login function in my angular app and have it communicate with the express backend i get the 504 error shown above. I've included snippets of what i think is all the relevant code below.

running on localhost:4200 trying to reach localhost:3000 that the server is being run on.

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const url = 'mongodb+srv://josh:*******@cluster0.cwv6f.mongodb.net/Unionise?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

const User = require('./models/user.model');

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : false}))

app.post('/api/user/login', (req, res) => {
    mongoose.connect(url,{ useMongoClient: true }, function(err){
        if(err) throw err;
        User.find({
            username : req.body.username, password : req.body.password
        }, function(err, user){
            if(err) throw err;
            if(user.length === 1){  
                return res.status(200).json({
                    status: 'success',
                    data: user
                })
            } else {
                return res.status(200).json({
                    status: 'fail',
                    message: 'Login Failed'
                })
            }
            
        })
    });
})

app.get('/api/user/login', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!')
})


app.listen(3000, () => console.log('blog server running on port 3000!'))
```

login.component.ts

```
import { AppService } from './../app.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';
import { User } from '../models/user.model';
import { response } from 'express';
import { Console } from 'console';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
    providers: [ LoginService ]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    public user : User;
    success = "";
    
    constructor(private loginService: LoginService, public appService: AppService) {
        this.user = new User();

        
    }
    
    validateLogin() {
        if(this.user.username && this.user.password) {
            this.loginService.validateLogin(this.user).subscribe(result => {
                console.log('result is ', result);
            }, error => {
                console.log('error is ', error);
            });
        } else {
            alert('enter user name and password');
        }
    }
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
        // this.appService.login().subscribe(
        //  response=>{
        //      this.success = response.status;
        //      console.log(this.success);
        //  },
        //  error => {}
        // );
    }
    
}
```

login.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { User } from '../models/user.model';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    
    constructor(private http: HttpClient){
        
    }
    
    validateLogin(user: User){
        return this.http.post('/api/user/login',{
            username : user.username,
            password : user.password
        })
    }
    
}
```

routing

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

proxy

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:3000",
        "secure": "false"
    }
}
```

Command console errors:
Angular app

```
<e> [webpack-dev-server] [HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:4200/api/user/login to http://localhost:3000/ [ECONNRESET] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

server

```
C:\Users\joshk\Documents\GitHub\Unionise\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:20
            throw error;
            ^

MongoParseError: option usemongoclient is not supported
    at parseOptions (C:\Users\joshk\Documents\GitHub\Unionise\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\connection_string.js:289:15)
    at new MongoClient (C:\Users\joshk\Documents\GitHub\Unionise\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:62:63)
    at C:\Users\joshk\Documents\GitHub\Unionise\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:784:16
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\joshk\Documents\GitHub\Unionise\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:781:19)
    at C:\Users\joshk\Documents\GitHub\Unionise\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:340:10
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\joshk\Documents\GitHub\Unionise\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:10:12)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\joshk\Documents\GitHub\Unionise\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1140:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\joshk\Documents\GitHub\Unionise\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:339:20)
    at C:\Users\joshk\Documents\GitHub\Unionise\server\app.js:20:11

Node.js v17.4.0
```

Comment: Any error code starting with `5` means it's the server's problem. Check your server logs and edit your question with the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that You're creating connection when request comes in.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const url = 'mongodb+srv://josh:*******@cluster0.cwv6f.mongodb.net/Unionise?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

const User = require('./models/user.model');

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : false}))

app.post('/api/user/login', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const query = {
      username: req.body.username, 
      password: req.body.password,
    };
    const user = await User.findOne(query).lean();

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(200).json({
        status: 'fail',
        message: 'Login Failed'
      });
    }

    res.status(200).json({
      status: 'success',
      data: user
    });
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res.status(500).end();
  }
})

app.get('/api/user/login', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!')
})


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// CONNECTION MUST BE ONCE AT START!
mongoose.connect(
  url, {},
  (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('DB: fail');
      console.error(err.message);
      process.exit(1);
    }
    console.log('DB: connected');
  
  
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('blog server running on port', PORT));
  });
```